# Youtube channel news - PHP script

Tags: php, scripting, youtube, youtube-channels

I need insert VIDEO NEWS block into footer of my website, which will be contain some latests videos uploaded on my youtube channel.
I don´t want original youtube API (for security and privacy reasons).

Is possible any standalone PHP parsing script to upload on my server, which will connect to youtube channel and generate only thumbnail and hyperlink to videos for my site?
I found some script for ZEND etc, but I don´t use zend.

Many thanks,
Petr

Comment: Yes, read this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started